# Keras with Tensorflow running out of memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm running an extremely large model with `IMAGE_SIZE = [2, 5928, 4728, 1]`

The model structure can be found below. We are using Tesla K80 to train that so we have 12GB of VRAM. We're using CUDA 9.0, Tensorflow 1.6.0 as backend for Keras 2.1.5. 
There's always some memory problems. I settled with `batch_size=1` because it failed otherwise. At first I couldn't even execute `fit()` for more then couple steps. It crashed with memory error. Then I restricted memory usage to 0.9 and it trained fine for some time. Right now I'm trying to load weights from previous training and I get memory error again.

Is there a way to debug this somehow? Why does it fail when I load weights? I would like to get any insight about what to do in this situation.

Thanks in advance.

```python
def make_model():
    img_1_inp = Input(shape=IMAGE_SIZE)
    img_2_inp = Input(shape=IMAGE_SIZE)

    conv_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[2, 2],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_1(img_1_inp)
    img_2 = conv_1(img_2_inp)

    batch_norm_1 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_1(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_1(img_2)

    activation_1 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_1(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_1(img_2)

    pooling_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))
    img_1 = pooling_1(img_1)
    img_2 = pooling_1(img_2)


    conv_2_1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[2, 2],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_2_1(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_2_1(img_2)

    batch_norm_2_1 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_2_1(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_2_1(img_2)

    activation_2_1 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_2_1(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_2_1(img_2)

    conv_2_2 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_2_2(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_2_2(img_2)

    batch_norm_2_2 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_2_2(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_2_2(img_2)

    activation_2_2 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_2_2(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_2_2(img_2)

    conv_2_3 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_2_3(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_2_3(img_2)

    batch_norm_2_3 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_2_3(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_2_3(img_2)

    activation_2_3 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_2_3(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_2_3(img_2)

    pooling_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))
    img_1 = pooling_2(img_1)
    img_2 = pooling_2(img_2)


    conv_3_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_3_1(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_3_1(img_2)

    batch_norm_3_1 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_3_1(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_3_1(img_2)

    activation_3_1 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_3_1(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_3_1(img_2)

    conv_3_2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_3_2(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_3_2(img_2)

    batch_norm_3_2 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_3_2(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_3_2(img_2)

    activation_3_2 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_3_2(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_3_2(img_2)

    conv_3_3 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_3_3(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_3_3(img_2)

    batch_norm_3_3 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_3_3(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_3_3(img_2)

    activation_3_3 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_3_3(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_3_3(img_2)

    pooling_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))
    img_1 = pooling_3(img_1)
    img_2 = pooling_3(img_2)


    conv_4_1 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_4_1(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_4_1(img_2)

    batch_norm_4_1 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_4_1(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_4_1(img_2)

    activation_4_1 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_4_1(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_4_1(img_2)

    conv_4_2 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[1, 1],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_4_2(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_4_2(img_2)

    batch_norm_4_2 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_4_2(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_4_2(img_2)

    activation_4_2 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_4_2(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_4_2(img_2)

    conv_4_3 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                     strides=[10, 10],
                     activation=None)
    img_1 = conv_4_3(img_1)
    img_2 = conv_4_3(img_2)

    batch_norm_4_3 = BatchNormalization()
    img_1 = batch_norm_4_3(img_1)
    img_2 = batch_norm_4_3(img_2)

    activation_4_3 = Activation('relu')
    img_1 = activation_4_3(img_1)
    img_2 = activation_4_3(img_2)

    g_pooling = GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last')
    img_1 = g_pooling(img_1)
    img_2 = g_pooling(img_2)

    # flat_1 = Flatten()
    # flatten_1 = flat_1(img_1)
    # flatten_2 = flat_1(img_2)
    #
    # merged = keras.layers.concatenate([flatten_1, flatten_2])
    merged = keras.layers.concatenate([img_1, img_2])
    dropout_1 = Dropout(0.2)
    merged = dropout_1(merged)
    dense_1 = (Dense(1024, activation='relu'))(merged)
    dropout_2 = Dropout(0.2)
    dense_1 = dropout_2(dense_1)
    dense_2 = (Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))(dense_1)

    model = Model(inputs=[img_1_inp, img_2_inp], output=dense_2)
    return model
```

Comment: I've never used memory restriction, did you also restrict the memory usage to 0.9 when loading the weights? I believe the input data is so big that you probably need the 12GB. I would try to load the weights in a model for smaller images (weights will be compatible), then try increasing image size until you find the maximum you can use?

Comment: @DanielGL yes, i use restriction in both cases. Do you mean like trying bulk data until it fails? I  actually don't understand how you can transfer weights. But most bizarre is this whole situation. Loading weights shouldn't increase memory usage, should it?

Comment: I guess not. Sorry I don't have any other idea :)